# jQuery `this` scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a global function defined in one place:

```
function addToCart (){
    var prodText = $(this).parent().siblings(".item1").text();
    $("#"+prodId+"shopC").children(".item1").text(prodText);
    alert(prodText);
}
```

Then, I want to call it inside a HTML element with an inline `onClick` event:
`onClick='addToCart()`'

It is not working, but it works if I put the function code directly inside the `onClick` event, so that must be a `this` scope issue.
There are many questions/explanations about `this` scope but I must confess I miss a simple straight answer for this specific case (I tried to use `"use strict"` with success either).
How to make this work?

Comment: Call it this way `onClick='addToCart(this)'` and in your method replace this with the parameter passed from here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per current implementation `this` doesn't refers to the element which invoked the function. It refers to `window` object.

You need to pass the current element context i.e. `this` to the function as

```
onClick='addToCart(this)'
```

and modify the function to accept element as  parameter.

```
function addToCart (elem){
    var prodText = $(elem).parent().siblings(".item1").text();
    $("#"+prodId+"shopC").children(".item1").text(prodText);
    alert(prodText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `this` inside a plain function will point to `window`. you have to pass the `this` context to the inline handler `onClick='addToCart(this)'`. Receive it and use it inside of event handler like below.

```
function addToCart (_this){
  var prodText = $(_this).parent().siblings(".item1").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass this keyword where you inline calling the addToCart function then you can capture that element

```
onClick='addToCart(this)'
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` object in your function does not point to the object where you added the `onClick` function to. It rather points to the `window` object.

You need to pass `this` as a param to your function.

```
function addToCart (trigger) { // Code goes here }
```

and call `addToCart(this)` in your `onClick`.

Learn more about [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in javascript here.